# Grok pattern for simple syslog

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Im using an ELK setup of 7.2.0 and filebeat 7.2.0.
Now I have enabled system module in filebeata nd im tryign to use a simple grok in Logstash,

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl  => false
  }
}
filter {
  if [fileset][module] == "system" {
          grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGLINE}"}
}
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["10.16.5.24:9200"]
    index => "rehatsystemlogs"
}
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Sample log : `Nov 17 08:01:01 strproelk02 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.`

Now when i check %{SYSLOGLINE} in https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ for this sample log, im able to get a proper output with my log split.

But when I execute my logstash, the separate columns are not split in my index in ES.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a curly brace missing, the end of filter,

```
 input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl  => false
  }
}
filter {
      grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGLINE}"}
       }
    }
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["10.16.5.24:9200"]
    index => "rehatsystemlogsdata"
}
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: I corrected it, it's still not splitting my data as expected. Kindly help me out, apologies for my delayed response.

Comment: please remove that if condition and check by keeping only the grok.

Comment: it did not work, how ever, a custom grok worked for me. Thanks !